# How to Transform the Limits of Integration?

Tags: calculus

Given $$I = \int^\frac{1}{2}_0{-\frac{\ln{(1-t)}}{t}}\,dt$$ and $f(1) = \int^1_0{\frac{\ln{(1-t)}}{t}}\,dt$, how would you transform the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ to $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ such that $$I = \int^1_\frac{1}{2}{-\frac{\ln{t}}{1-t}}\,dt?$$

(In case it helps to know, the original integral I was working with was $f(x) = \int^x_0{-\frac{\ln{(1-t)}}{t}}\,dt$, so in the context of this problem, $I = f(\frac{1}{2})$)

Comment: those expressions for $f(x)$ are incompatible; the latter does not depend on $x$ at all

Comment: Still no $x$ ...

Comment: Ok, there. That should clarify some

Comment: It looks like you just need a $u=1-t$ substitution.

Comment: Peter, would you be able to show your work? I tried that substitution but I didn't know how to change the limits of integration. Thanks!

Comment: What's given and what do you want to find?

Comment: @Mhenni: No other given information is needed. The primary premise of the problem is to rewrite the original integral $I$ by changing its interval from $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ to $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. As Peter said, a substitution is used (which is why the integrand is changed slightly). However, I do understand how/why the limits of integration are adjusted to $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ after the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the substitution $u=1-t$, we have $t=1-u$ and $dt=-du$.

Additionally, when $t=\frac{1}{2}$, we have $u=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ and when $t=0$, we have $u=1-0=1$.

Hence our integral transforms as follows:
$$\int^\frac{1}{2}_0-{\frac{\ln{(1-t)}}{t}}\,dt=\int^\frac{1}{2}_1-{\frac{\ln(u)}{1-u}}\,(-du)=-\int^\frac{1}{2}_1-{\frac{\ln(u)}{1-u}}\,du=\int^1_\frac{1}{2}-{\frac{\ln(u)}{1-u}}\,du,$$

where in the last step we have used the fact that $-\int^b_af(x)\,dx=\int^a_bf(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Oh, wow. I see where I made a misstep in my initial attempt. Thank you very much for writing everything out.

Comment: @user155812 Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need $u = 1-t$ and the negative sign takes care of the interval from $1/2 \to 1$

This is actually a polylogarithm.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} -\frac{\log(1-t) dt}{t} = Li_2(\frac{1}{2})$$

$$Li_2(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

$$Li_2(1/2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^nn^2}$$